# Why is opening a file slower than loading a module?

Tags: python

Why is opening and closing a file slower than loading a module (which has to read and load the modules files)?

Opening and closing a file:

```
$ python timeit 'open("test.tmp", "r").close()'
50000 loops, best of 5: 5.36 usec per loop
```

Loading a module:

```
$ python timeit 'import requests; requests.get'
5000000 loops, best of 5: 98.3 nsec per loop
```

**Edit:**

It seems that `requests` is not being reimported at each loop.
If I force it to be reimported at each loop, the results make sense.

```
$ python -m timeit 'import requests; import sys; del sys.modules["requests"]'
2000 loops, best of 5: 211 usec per loop
```

Comment: Modules get cached.

Comment: So `timeit` is not clearing the cache in each execution

Comment: Right, why would it? It times, nothing else.  Also, what would be the point of caching if you clear the cache immediately?

Comment: I was thinking that as benchmark tool it would make every run equal, but  benchmarking module loadings is such corner case that it does not make sense. Also, no caching it could put some noise on other more common benchmarks. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: It does not know what you want to benchmark. It can't know. It just times. Keep it simple. If you want to clear the cache in between, you can probably put that in the code you time. (I'd have to look up how to clear the module cache / unload a module; not sure if this is possible at all.)

Comment: I believe loaded modules are stored on `sys.modules`, deleting the key from there is enough to force it reloading, see edit